# htaccess Multiple Rewrite Rules Not Working In XAMPP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, xampp

I Currently have 2 rules:

The first replace "domain.com/profile/user" to "domain.com/profile.php?user=user"

The second rule removes the .php from all of the files so that they can be accessed without the need for .php.

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

In its current state, the first rule works and the second does not work.

However, if i add "Options +MultiViews" to the top so that it is:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Then the first rule does not work while the second one does work?

I just can't figure out how to get them both working.

Note i am using a XAMPP vhost for the web server and have changed the relevant settings to allow htaccess to work with XAMPP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution, not the best but it works.

I simply changed my .php remover to another version which achieves the same task.

I don't know why this works and the other version doesnt. If you know why the origional one does not work then please let me know.

Here is the working version:

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-hide-php-extension-in-url-using-htaccess